# Rails Migrations: Check Existence and Keep Going?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I was doing this kind of thing in my migrations:

```
add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string rescue puts "column already added"
```

but it turns out that, **while this works for SQLite, it does not work for PostgreSQL**. It seems like if the add_column blows up, **even if the Exception is caught,** the transaction is dead and so the Migration can't do any additional work.

Is there any **non-DB sepecific** ways to check if a column or table already exist? Failing that, is there any way to get my rescue block to really work?

Comment: It need to be mentioned, that conditional migration leads to problems with rollback due to the fact that at the rollback stage it is not known what conditions were during the forward migration

Comment: Only do the non optional part in rollback

Answer (score 193, accepted):

As of Rails 3.0 and later, you can use [`column_exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F) to check for the existance of a column.

```
unless column_exists? :statuses, :hold_reason
  add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string
end
```

There's also a [`table_exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/table_exists%3F) function, which goes as far back as Rails 2.1.

Comment: Is it considered best practice to check if a column/table exists before add/create it? (I know of course it depends on the problem in hands)

Comment: Does this work with rollbacks if I define it in change method?

Comment: Yeah rollback would be a issue... we're not sure whether we should remove the column or not.. since we're not recording the previous state.

Answer (score 13):

**Rails 6.1+:**

```
add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string, if_not_exists: true
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38352/files

**Rails < 6.1:**

```
add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string unless column_exists?(:statuses, :hold_reason)
```

Answer (score 10):

Or even shorter

```
add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string unless column_exists? :statuses, :hold_reason
```

Comment: this would be a comment on the other answer, not an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For **Rails 2.X**, you can check the existence of columns with the following:

```
columns("[table-name]").index {|col| col.name == "[column-name]"}
```

If it returns nil, no such column exists. If it returns a Fixnum, then the column does exist. Naturally, you can put more selective parameters between the `{...}` if you want to identify a column by more than just its name, for example:

```
{ |col| col.name == "foo" and col.sql_type == "tinyint(1)" and col.primary == nil }
```

(this answer first posted on [How to write conditional migrations in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980895/how-to-write-conditional-migrations-in-rails/9912032#9912032))

Answer (score 0):

`add_column :statuses, :hold_reason, :string unless Status.column_names.include?("hold_reason")`