# How to write conditional migrations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am looking for ways to write migrations in rails that can be executed against the database many times without failing.

For instance let say I have this migration:

```
class AddUrlToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :profile, :url, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :profile, :url
  end
end
```

If the `url` column already exists in the `Profile` table (if the schema.rb has been modified unexpectedly for instance), my migration will fail saying that it's a duplicate!

So how to execute this migration only if it has to?

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class AddUrlToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Profile.reset_column_information
    add_column(:profile, :url, :string) unless Profile.column_names.include?('url')

  end

  def self.down
    Profile.reset_column_information
    remove_column(:profile, :url) if Profile.column_names.include?('url')
  end
end
```

This will reset the column information before it begins - making sure that the Profile model has the up-to-date column information from the actual table. It will then only add the column if it doesn't exist. The same thing happens for the down function, but it only removes the column if it exists.

If you have multiple use cases for this you could factor the code out into a function and re-use that in your migrations.

Comment: FYI: it's generally a bad idea to reference models explicitly in your migration - what if that model is removed in the future?  Or changes?  Instead, create an single-use model by adding ```class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base ; end``` at the top of the migration class definition.

Comment: I ran into this issue when going back and forth between branches. I had run a migration on another branch that effected the staging database and neglected to rollback the migration.  Then later when re-introducing the migration I got errors that the field already existed. (This was a span of a couple of months so many other migration had already been run)

Commenting out the migration worked fine when deploying to staging again but the field was actually missing from production db. This simple check to see if the field exists before running migration was the fix that I needed

Answer (score 15):

For **Rails 3.X**, there's the `column_exists?(:table_name, :column_name)` method.

For **Rails 2.X**, you can check the existence of columns with the following:

```
columns("<table name>").index {|col| col.name == "<column name>"}
```

...or if you're not in a migration file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns("<table name>").index {|col| col.name == "<column name>"}
```

If it returns nil, no such column exists. If it returns a Fixnum, then the column does exist. Naturally, you can put more selective parameters between the `{...}` if you want to identify a column by more than just its name, for example:

```
{ |col| col.name == "foo" and col.sql_type == "tinyint(1)" and col.primary == nil }
```

Answer (score 10):

This should work

```
def self.table_exists?(name)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?(name)
end

if table_exists?(:profile) && !Profile.column_names.include?("url")
  add_column :profile, :url, :string
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping my migration in a conditional worked for me.
**Rails 4.X**

```
class AddUrlToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  unless Profile.column_names.include?("url")
    def self.up
      add_column :profile, :url, :string
    end

    def self.down
      remove_column :profile, :url
    end
  end
end
```