# On Heroku, a table is dropped, yet an old migration on it is still being run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my Rails app, I had originally created a table called `items` which has since been dropped and replaced with a different table called `products`. The `items` table has an old migration (which was obviously created before the migration that dropped it) that modifies the serial number field, but this migration fails when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`:

```
=  ChangeSerialNumberToString: migrating =====================================
-- change_column(:items, :serial_number, :text)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "items" ALTER COLUMN "serial_number"
```

It seems that it's trying to run a migration on the dropped table, which obviously fails because the table doesn't exist anymore.

On my local server, `rake db:migrate` runs fine, but `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` results in the following error:

```
==  ChangeSerialNumberToString: migrating =====================================
-- change_column(:items, :serial_number, :text)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Could not find table 'items'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `ChangeSerialNumberToString` migration from your db/migrate directory, commit the changes to heroku and then run the migration.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks! However, I had to also delete the migration that dropped the table (as that was causing the same error); wouldn't this cause a problem for other people who need the migration for deleting the table on their instance of the app?

Comment: didn't quite get your question.  is your app available for people to download and deploy?

Comment: Sorry, I mean for other devs who may already have the `items` table in their install of the app, and now need to remove it.

Comment: yea, they'll need to update from your latest version. in addition to that, you can provide a custom migration script that will check for the unwanted table (items) and delete it.  Take a look at Fernando's answer on this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980895/how-to-write-conditional-migrations-in-rails